# Javascript Uncaught Exception in Promise

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript and have the following function:

```
createChat(img1: string, img2: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        console.log('firebase craete');
        return this.af.database.list('/chat/').push({
            memberId1: this.me.uid,
            memberId2: this.you.uid,
            img1: img1,
            img2: img2,
            displayName1: this.me.displayName,
            displayName2: this.you.displayName,
            lastMsg_text: '',
            lastMsg_read1: true,
            lastMsg_read2: true,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            negativtimestamp: -Date.now()
        }).then((item) => {
            console.log('firebase craete resolve', item.key);
            resolve(item.key);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error creating chat', error);
        });
    });
}
```

and get the following output:

[image]

As you can see the Promise's `resolve` is being called, and it returns a value as expected. Do you know why I am getting the `Exception`?

Comment: You've got a Promise anti-pattern there - since `.push` returns a promise there's no need to create a new one inside your function

Comment: Thanks, but It creates a `ThenableReference`, `(method) FirebaseListObservable<any[]>.push(val: any): firebase.database.ThenableReference`.  How do I do it, if I want it to resolve the `item.key`?

Answer (score 1):

You've created a Promise anti-pattern, by wrapping your own Promise around a function that already returns a Promise (or `Thenable`)

You should:

1. not catch the error there, but allow it to propagate upwards
2. use `.then` internally to extract and return the field you require:

So:

```
createChat(img1: string, img2: string): ThenableReference<string> {
    return this.af.database.list('/chat/').push({
        memberId1: this.me.uid,
        memberId2: this.you.uid,
        img1: img1,
        img2: img2,
        displayName1: this.me.displayName,
        displayName2: this.you.displayName,
        lastMsg_text: '',
        lastMsg_read1: true,
        lastMsg_read2: true,
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        negativtimestamp: -Date.now()
    }).then(item => item.key);
}
```

NB: I'm not familiar with TypeScript, so the return type indicated above is probably incorrect.